# Concatenation of Distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic, distributions

I would like to calculate mean, variance, ... of a concatenation of distributions (is this the correct technical term?). For an easy example I am trying to calculate the mean of a PoissonDistribution where the position parameter is normally distributed. The following does not produce the desired result of *m*:

```
Mean[PoissonDistribution[NormalDistribution[m, 1]]]
```

Comment: The general term is "hierarchical modeling".  There are Frequentist and Bayesian approaches.  Here's a link to a Bayesian definition:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling.  (Note that there are lots of other uses of the term "hierarchical modeling" so searching for that term will get you stuff that doesn't match what you want to do.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ParameterMixtureDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParameterMixtureDistribution.html)

```
Mean @ ParameterMixtureDistribution[PoissonDistribution[λ],
  Distributed[ λ, NormalDistribution[m, 1]]]
```

> ```
> Undefined
> ```

We need to use a distribution with positive support for the distribution of `λ`:

```
Mean @ ParameterMixtureDistribution[PoissonDistribution[λ],
  Distributed[ λ, LogNormalDistribution[m, 1]]]
```

> ```
>   E^(1/2 + m)
> ```

```
Mean @ ParameterMixtureDistribution[PoissonDistribution[λ], 
  Distributed[λ, ExponentialDistribution[τ]]]
```

> -1 + (1 + τ)/τ

Comment: Thank you very much, ParameterMixtureDistribution was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @jitter, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.